# calling overloaded function with default arguments in Kotlin

Tags: oop, kotlin, default-value, overloading, calling-convention

Hi i am confused in invoking concept of a function with default arguments in case of function overloading. 
My use case is -
i have two functions with same name(function overloading) and i have added few default arguments, so it is not clear which function will be called.
Example-

```
fun add(a:Int, b:Int=2, c:Int=2):Int
{
    return a+b+c
}


fun add(a:Int, b:Int=1):Int
{
    return a+b
}
```

Now i am calling

```
add(5)
add(5,2)
```

which method should be called.

if i check

```
fun foo(p1:Int,p2:String?=null)
```

fun foo(p1:Int,p2:Int=0)

this will cause of
"overload resolution ambiguity" error.

But in my case every time  `fun add(a:Int, b:Int=1):Int
    {
        return a+b
    }`

is called.
So how ?

Comment: What happens when you tried it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [kotlin overload method with default parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49933101/kotlin-overload-method-with-default-parameter)

Comment: actually not a duplicate since this is not an ambiguity: https://pl.kotl.in/BJO4ZTacQ seems the compiler does prefer the closer match parameter count wise

Comment: everytime 2nd function call,                               fun add(a:Int, b:Int=1):Int
{
    return a+b
}

Answer (score 0):

**2nd function (`fun add(a:Int, b:Int=1):Int`) is called because it is a closer match** (less parameter difference) as *zapl* pointed out.

***DETAILS:***

Resolution of overloaded method calls with default params is [described in Kotlinlang spec](https://kotlinlang.org/spec/overload-resolution.html#rationale-1:%7E:text=The%20candidate%20with%20the%20least%20number%20of%20non%2Dspecified%20default%20parameters%20is%20a%20more%20specific%20candidate):

> The candidate with the least number of non-specified default
> parameters is a more specific candidate

So when you call `add(5)`, then the number of non-specified default parameters is:

- 2 for `fun add(a:Int, b:Int=2, c:Int=2):Int`
- 1 for `fun add(a:Int, b:Int=1):Int`

That's why the 2nd function is called. Based on the same logic, the 2nd function wins also when `add(5,2)` is called.

But when you have that 3rd function (`fun foo(p1:Int,p2:String?=null)`), the compiler can't decide which one to call, because the *parameter difference* is the same. Based on docs:

> If there are still more than one most specific candidate afterwards, this is an overload ambiguity which must be reported as a compile-time error.